# Is there a way to get the value of a HashMap randomly in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Is there a way to get the value of a HashMap randomly in Java?

Comment: Why do you need this? If it's anything other than testing, you're using the wrong data structure. If it's for testing, then you probably don't want random data.

Comment: See my answer below -- the appropriate way to do this depends a little on your circumstances (notably how many random elements you need per change to the map).

Comment: If you want something efficient, take a look at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919734/selecting-random-key-and-value-sets-from-a-map-in-java/20724193#20724193 Hashtables are in principle a great structure for accessing random elements. It's unfortunate that the Java api doesn't give us an easy way to do it.

Comment: @kdgregory hi, I know it's an old thread, but I wonder why you're saying its the wrong data structure for random access? Thanks

Comment: @RegUser - HashMaps are designed to be accessed by key rather than value. There are uses for bidirectional mappings, but you should choose a class designed for that purpose and not try force HashMap to do something that it wasn't designed to do.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This works:

```
Random generator = new Random();
Object[] values = myHashMap.values().toArray();
Object randomValue = values[generator.nextInt(values.length)];
```

If you want the random value to be a type other than an `Object` simply add a cast to the last line.  So if `myHashMap` was declared as:

```
Map<Integer,String> myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

The last line can be:

```
String randomValue = (String) values[generator.nextInt(value.length)];
```

---

The below **doesn't work**, `Set.toArray()` always returns an array of `Object`s, which can't be coerced into an array of `Map.Entry`.

```
Random generator = new Random();
Map.Entry[] entries = myHashMap.entrySet().toArray();
randomValue = entries[generator.nextInt(entries.length)].getValue();
```

Comment: when executing your code Tom I get the exception "incompatible types-found java.util.object[] but expected java.util.entry[]"

Comment: How to do the necessary type casting?I have tried to Map, Map.Entry the message displayed is inconvertible types

Comment: Hi Varuna, you're quite correct, that code was broken!  I've added some code to my answer that does work.

Comment: The post below this by coobird is also correct and it works But I choose this as the correct solution because this more simple

Comment: If you want to use the first method, use the overloaded `toArray(T[] arr)` method, `Map.Entry<K, V>[] entries = s.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[s.size()]);` (you should have a warning though because you cannot create a parametrized array)

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You may want to consider using [`toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) with a size 0 array to avoid a cast.

Comment: Hi, can you edit the answer so it doesn't contain not-working part? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 36):

Since the requirements only asks for a random value from the `HashMap`, here's the approach:

1. The [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has a [`values`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values()) method which returns a [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of the values in the map.
2. The `Collection` is used to create a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
3. The [`size`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method is used to find the size of the `List`, which is used by the [`Random.nextInt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method to get a random index of the `List`.
4. Finally, the value is retrieved from the `List` [`get`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method with the random index.

Implementation:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Hello", 10);
map.put("Answer", 42);

List<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(valuesList.size());
Integer randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);
```

The nice part about this approach is that all the methods are [generic](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) -- there is no need for typecasting.

Comment: Dear coobird your code is correct is and it works But I choose the above by Tom since it appears to me as more simple!!!!!
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11):

Should you need to draw futher values from the map without repeating any elements you can put the map into a List and then shuffle it.

```
List<Object> valuesList = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());
Collections.shuffle( valuesList );

for ( Object obj : valuesList ) {
    System.out.println( obj );
}
```

Comment: +1 for Collections.shuffle(); I hadn't seen that before.  Cool; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between 0 and the number of keys in your `HashMap`. Get the key at the random number. Get the value from that key.

**Pseudocode**:

```
 int n =  random(map.keys().length());
 String key = map.keys().at(n);
 Object value = map.at(key);
```

If it's hard to implement this in Java, then you could create and array from this code using the `toArray()` function in `Set`.

```
 Object[] values = map.values().toArray(new Object[map.size()]);
 Object random_value = values[random(values.length)];
```

I'm not really sure how to do the random number.

Comment: except that's untranslatable to Java, since the keys of a Map are a Set, and Sets don't have any sense of position

Comment: Removing the downvote because you looked up the correct methods (although I still think the OP needs to rethink the problem). Take a look at java.lang.Random for the random number.

Answer (score 2):

Converting it to an array and then getting the value is too slow when its in the hot path.

so get the set (either the key or keyvalue set) and do something like:

```
    public class SetUtility {
        public static<Type> Type getRandomElementFromSet(final Set<Type> set, Random random) {
        final int index = random.nextInt(set.size());

        Iterator<Type> iterator = set.iterator();

        for( int i = 0; i < index-1; i++ ) {
            iterator.next();
        }

        return iterator.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good answer depends slightly on the circumstances, in particular how often you need to get a random key for a given map (N.B. the technique is essentially the same whether you take key or value).

- If you need **various random keys**
  from a given map, **without the map
  changing** in between getting the
  random keys, then use the **[random
  sampling method](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/random_sample.shtml)** as you iterate
  through the key set. Effectively what
  you do is iterate over the set
  returned by keySet(), and on each
  item calculate the probability of
  wanting to take that key, given how
  many you will need overall and the
  number you've taken so far. Then
  generate a random number and see if
  that number is lower than the
  probability. (N.B. **This method will always work**, even if you only need 1 key; it's just not necessarily the most efficient way in that case.)
- The keys in a HashMap are effectively
  in pseudo-random order already. In an
  extreme case where you will **only
  ever need one random key** for a
  given possible map, you could even just
  pull out the **first element of the
  keySet()**.
- In **other cases** (where you either
  need multiple possible random keys
  for a given possible map, or the map
  will change between you taking random
  keys), you essentially have to
  **create or maintain an array/list** of the keys from which you select a
  random key.

Comment: ... except that the OP wanted random values, not keys

Comment: ah sorry missed that -- the same essentially applies, though whether you take the key or value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, `findAny` function in a pretty solution:

```
MyEntityClass myRandomlyPickedObject = myHashMap.values().stream().findAny();
```

Comment: This is bad practice as it's replacing a HashMap read O(1) by a linear iteration O(n). Acceptable for small Maps, but you're doomed if size grows. In short: Don't do convenience coding if you're saving one or two lines. Never.

Comment: All the other high voted answers are linear, which iterate over all the elements. Here, at least, not all elements must be iterated over.

Comment: Ran some tests and it seems that `findAny()` doesn't always randomize.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all other high voted answers iterate over all the elements. Here, at least, not all elements must be iterated over:

```
Random generator = new Random();
return myHashMap.values().stream()
                .skip(random.nextInt(myHashMap.size()))
                .findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use the arrays approach described by Peter Stuifzand, also through the `values()`-method:

```
// Populate the map
// ...

Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
Object[] values = map.values().toArray();

Random rand = new Random();

// Get random key (and value, as an example)
String randKey = keys[ rand.nextInt(keys.length) ];
String randValue = values[ rand.nextInt(values.length) ];

// Use the random key
System.out.println( map.get(randKey) );
```

Comment: This returns a random key and value, but, not a pair that is a key-value mapping in the map!

Comment: Yes, but the example was to show how to randomize keys and values (see OPs comment from the post above this). :) I will clarify the example, though.

Comment: ("post above" meaning Kazar's, the order changed.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i really don't know why you want to do this... but if it helps, i've created a RandomMap that automatically randomizes the values when you call values(), then the following runnable demo application might do the job...

```
  package random;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;
  import java.util.TreeMap;

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Map hashMap = makeHashMap();
          // you can make any Map random by making them a RandomMap
          // better if you can just create the Map as a RandomMap instead of HashMap
          Map randomMap = new RandomMap(hashMap);

          // just call values() and iterate through them, they will be random
          Iterator iter = randomMap.values().iterator();

          while (iter.hasNext()) {
              String value = (String) iter.next();
              System.out.println(value);
          }
      }

      private static Map makeHashMap() {
          Map retVal;

          // HashMap is not ordered, and not exactly random (read the javadocs)
          retVal = new HashMap();

          // TreeMap sorts your map based on Comparable of keys
          retVal = new TreeMap();

          // RandomMap - a map that returns stuff randomly
          // use this, don't have to create RandomMap after function returns
          // retVal = new HashMap();

          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
              retVal.put("key" + i, "value" + i);
          }

          return retVal;
      }
  }

  /**
   * An implementation of Map that shuffles the Collection returned by values().
   * Similar approach can be applied to its entrySet() and keySet() methods.
   */
  class RandomMap extends HashMap {
      public RandomMap() {
          super();
      }

      public RandomMap(Map map) {
          super(map);
      }

      /**
       * Randomize the values on every call to values()
       *
       * @return randomized Collection
       */
      @Override
      public Collection values() {
          List randomList = new ArrayList(super.values());
          Collections.shuffle(randomList);

          return randomList;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not really want a **random** value but rather just **any** value, and then it's nice doing this:

```
Object selectedObj = null;
for (Object obj : map.values()) {
    selectedObj = obj;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Question is about getting random element. Not the first.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility to retrieve a random entry, key, or value from a map, entry set, or iterator.

Since you cannot and should not be able to figure out the size of an iterator ([Guava can do this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#size(java.util.Iterator))) you will have to overload the `randEntry()` method to accept a size which should be the length of the entries.

```
package util;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                put("Foo", 1);
                put("Bar", 2);
                put("Baz", 3);
            }
        };

        System.out.println(randEntryValue(map));
    }

    static <K, V> Entry<K, V> randEntry(Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it, int count) {
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * count);

        while (index > 0 && it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();
            index--;
        }

        return it.next();
    }

    static <K, V> Entry<K, V> randEntry(Set<Entry<K, V>> entries) {
        return randEntry(entries.iterator(), entries.size());
    }

    static <K, V> Entry<K, V> randEntry(Map<K, V> map) {
        return randEntry(map.entrySet());
    }

    static <K, V> K randEntryKey(Map<K, V> map) {
        return randEntry(map).getKey();
    }

    static <K, V> V randEntryValue(Map<K, V> map) {
        return randEntry(map).getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with `O(n)` time complexity you can use methods like `values()` or `values().toArray()` but if you look for a constant `O(1)` `getRandom()` operation one great alternative is to use a custom data structure. `ArrayList` and `HashMap` can be combined to attain `O(1)` time for `insert()`, `remove()` and `getRandom()`. Here is an example implementation:

```
class RandomizedSet {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> valToIdx = new HashMap<>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    public RandomizedSet() { }

    /**
     * Inserts a value to the set. Returns true if the set did not already contain
     * the specified element.
     */
    public boolean insert(int val) {
        if (!valToIdx.containsKey(val)) {
            valToIdx.put(val, nums.size());
            nums.add(val);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Removes a value from the set. Returns true if the set contained the specified
     * element.
     */
    public boolean remove(int val) {
        if (valToIdx.containsKey(val)) {
            int idx = valToIdx.get(val);
            int lastVal = nums.get(nums.size() - 1);

            nums.set(idx, lastVal);
            valToIdx.put(lastVal, idx);

            nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
            valToIdx.remove(val);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Get a random element from the set. */
    public int getRandom() {
        return nums.get(rand.nextInt(nums.size()));
    }
}
```

The idea comes from [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/) problem from [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what your key is - the nature of a hashmap doesn't allow for this to happen easily.

The way I can think of off the top of my head is to select a random number between 1 and the size of the hashmap, and then start iterating over it, maintaining a count as you go - when count is equal to that random number you chose, that is your random element.

Comment: Kazer
     The key and the value I in my map are both of type String, it is in this situation that I have faced this problem.There is a value() method which returns a collections view according to the documentation, is it possible through this to take only the HashMap 
values(not keys) and get a random value?

Comment: Of course, though this then raises the question of why you're using a hash map in the first place...