# Selecting random key and value sets from a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, random, hashmap, treemap

I want to get random keys and their respective values from a Map. The idea is that a random generator would pick a key and display that value. The tricky part is that both key and value will be strings, for example `myMap.put("Geddy", "Lee")`.

Comment: What are your performance criteria? There's an O(n) solution to pick a random element from an arbitrary sequence, but if you're going to be picking random elements a *lot* from the same map, you might want to create a list of the keys so you can just pick a random number and go from that.

Comment: I have two ways that I envision this: a key is called randomly and displayed, the user enters a value, the value entered is checked against the value stored with the key. From my example above, let's say the user is asked "What is Geddy's last name?" (where "Geddy" would be taken as a string from the key), the user enters "Smith". "Smith" is then checked against the value "Lee", etc...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> x;

Random       random    = new Random();
List<String> keys      = new ArrayList<String>(x.keySet());
String       randomKey = keys.get( random.nextInt(keys.size()) );
String       value     = x.get(randomKey);
```

Comment: I would place the entrySet() into the List.

Comment: I should add that I didn't reveal that I had to implement this in Android. Ultimately I ended up using SharedPreferences -> Map and Map -> ArrayList.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

This question should be of help to you [Is there a way to get the value of a HashMap randomly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929554/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-value-of-a-hashmap-randomly-in-java) and this one also [Picking a random element from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set) because `HashMap` is backed by a `HashSet`. It would be either `O(n)` time and constant space or it would be `O(n)` extra space and constant time.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the wasted space, one approach would be to separately keep a `List` of all keys that are in the `Map`. For best performance, you'll want a `List` that has good random-access performance (like an `ArrayList`). Then, just get a random number between 0 (inclusive) and `list.size()` (exclusive), pull out the key at that index, and look that key up.

```
Random rand = something
int randIndex = rand.nextInt(list.size());
K key = list.get(randIndex);
V value = map.get(key);
```

This approach also means that adding a key-value pair is a good deal cheaper than removing one. To add the key-value pair, you would test to see if the key is already in the map (if your values can be null, you'll have to separately call `map.containsKey`; if not, you can just add the key-value pair and see if the "old value" it returns is `null)`. If the key is already in the map, the list is unchanged, but if not, you add the key to the list (an O(1) operation for most lists). Removing a key-value pair, though, involves an O(N) operation to remove the key from the list.

If space is a big concern, but performance is less so, you could also get an `Iterator` over the map's entry set (`Map.entrySet()`), and skip `randIndex` entries before returning the one you want. But that would be an O(N) operation, which kinda defeats the whole point of a map.

Finally, you can just get the entry set's `toArray()` and randomly index into that. That's simpler, though less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

if your keys are integer, or something comparable, you can use TreeMap to do that.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
int key = RandomUtils.ranInt(treeMap.lastKey());
int value = treeMap.ceilingKey(key);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would copy the Map into an array and select the entry you want at random. This avoid the need to also lookup the value from the key.

```
Map<String, String> x = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map.Entry<String,String>[] entries = x.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
Random rand = new Random();

// call repeatedly
Map.Entry<String, String> keyValue = entries[rand.nextInt(entries.length)];
```

---

If you want to avoid duplication, you can randomize the order of the entries

```
Map<String, String> x = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<Map.Entry<String,String>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>> (x.entrySet());
Collections.shuffle(entries);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to select a list of random keys, then insert them into a map (along with their corresponding values in the source map.)

This way you do not need to copy the whole `keySet` into an array, only the selected keys.

```
public static <K, V>Map<K, V> sampleFromMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> source, int n, Random rnd) {
    List<K> chosenKeys = new ArrayList<K>();
    int count = 0;
    for (K k: source.keySet()) {
        if (count++ < n) {
            chosenKeys.add(k);
            if (count == n) {
                Collections.shuffle(chosenKeys, rnd);
            }
        } else {
            int pos = rnd.nextInt(count);
            if (pos < n) {
                chosenKeys.set(pos, k);
            }
        }
    }
    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (K k: chosenKeys) {
        result.put(k, source.get(k));
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
}
```

Comment: Although this is sound in theory, doesn't `keySet()` already allocate into a

Answer (score 0):

```
In some cases you might want to preserve an order you put the elements in the Set,
In such scenario you can use, This 

Set<Integer> alldocsId = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i=0;i<normalized.length;i++)
            {
                String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT movieID FROM postingtbl WHERE term=?";
                PreparedStatement prepstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                prepstm.setString(1,normalized[i]);
                ResultSet rs = prepstm.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    alldocsId.add(rs.getInt("MovieID"));
                }
                prepstm.close();
            }

        List<Integer> alldocIDlst = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator it = alldocsId.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            alldocIDlst.add(Integer.valueOf(it.next().toString()));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Been a while since a played with java, but doesn't keySet() give you a list that you can select from using a numerical index? I think you could pick a random number and select that from the keySet of myMap, then select the corresponding value from myMap. Can't test this right now, but it seems to strike me as possible!

Comment: No, as the name suggests that returns a `Set` and not a `List`. So yes, you can pick a random key from a `Set` but not as straightforward (nor as fast) as from a `List`