# Random access for HashMap keys

Tags: java, hashmap, key, random-access

I need to randomly access keys in a HashMap. Right now, I am using **Set**'s toArray() method on the **Set** that **HashMap**'s keySet() returns, and casting it as a String[] (my keys are Strings). Then I use **Random** to pick a random element of the String array.

```
public String randomKey() {
    String[] keys = (String[]) myHashMap.keySet().toArray();
    Random rand = new Random();
    return keyring[rand.nextInt(keyring.length)];
}
```

It seems like there ought to be a more elegant way of doing this! 
I've read the following post, but it seems even more convoluted than the way I'm doing it. If the following solution is the better, why is that so?[Selecting random key and value sets from a Map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919734/selecting-random-key-and-value-sets-from-a-map-in-java)

Comment: That's not bad. Just three lines of code and neatly packed away in an easy-to-use/easy-to-understand method.

Comment: But you should check for the empty map first.

Comment: Have I not read that the `Random` variable should be kept external to the method else the above code will not give a good level of randomness? quote: If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Comment: @MohamedEl-Beltagy, I am working on a Markov Text Generation assignment for a CS2 class. I make a key out of each string of k length that occurs in a source text. The value that corresponds to that key is a string of all the chars (with duplicates) that follow each occurrence of that string in the source text. To generate random source-like text, start with a random key, concatenate it with a random character from its string, update the seed so it contains k chars, and repeat. The trouble happens when the seed/key has no value in the map, necessitating that I randomly pick another seed/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility in a `HashMap` to return an entry without knowing the key so, if you want to use only that class, what you have is probably as good a solution as any.

Keep in mind however that you're not actually *restricted* to using a `HashMap`.

If you're going to be reading this collection *far* more often than writing it, you can create your *own* class which contains both a `HashMap` of the mappings and a different collection of the keys that allows random access (like a `Vector`).

That way, you won't incur the cost of converting the map to a set then an array every time you *read,* it will only happen when necessary (adding or deleting items from your collection).

Unfortunately, a `Vector` allows *multiple* keys of the same value so you would have to defend against that when inserting (to ensure fairness when selecting a random key). That will increase the cost of insertion.

Deletion would also be increased cost since you would have to search for the item to remove from the vector.

I'm not sure there's an easy single collection for this purpose. If you wanted to go the whole hog, you could have your current `HashMap`, a `Vector` of the keys, and yet *another* `HashMap` mapping the keys to the vector indexes.

That way, all operations (insert, delete, change, get-random) would be O(1) in time, very efficient in terms of time, perhaps less so in terms of space :-)

Or there's a halfway solution that still uses a wrapper but creates a long-lived array of strings whenever you insert, change or delete a key. That way, you only create the array when needed and you still amortise the costs. Your class then uses the hashmap for efficient access with a key, and the array for random selection.

And the change there is minimal. You already have the code for creating the array, you just have to create your wrapper class which provides whatever you need from a `HashMap` (and simply passes most calls *through* to the `HashMap`) plus one extra function to get a random key (using the array).

---

Now, I'd only consider using those methods if performance is actually a problem though. You can spend untold hours making your code faster in ways that don't matter :-)

If what you have is fast enough, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `Collections.shuffle` method, saved to a variable and simply pop one off the top as required.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Comment: Concise, but seems to be unnecessarily slow for large maps. No need to shuffle all of them to just pick one.

Comment: I do not see where the OP says he is just going to pick one.  I suggested to save the shuffled list fore re-use.

Comment: Okay, if the map does not change and you want to repeatedly get a random key, that would work well. With your approach you could even get "choose-without-replacement" if required.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid copying the whole keyset into a temporary data structure, by first getting the size, choosing the random index and then iterating over the keyset the appropriate number of times.

This code would need to be synchronized to avoid concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want any element of a set, this will work fine.

```
String s = set.iterator().next();
```

If you are unsure whether there is an element in the set, use:

```
String s;
Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    s = it.next();
}
else {
    // set was empty
}
```