# randomly generating selectively keys in a hashmap

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the value of a HashMap randomly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929554/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-value-of-a-hashmap-randomly-in-java)

I want to generate random keys and show their associated values in a Hashmap but not all the keys. For example if there are 40 key value pairs I just want 10 to be randomly displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
List keys = new ArrayList(theHashMap.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(keys.size(), 10); ++i) {
  map.get(keys[i]);
}
```